# Where to put the event subscriber

Tags: laravel-5

Is a correct way if I put a Subscriber in the root method of the EventServiceProvider in the Laravel 5?

```
/**
 * Register any other events for your application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
 * @return void
 */
 public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
 {
    parent::boot($events);

    \Event::subscribe(new Subscriber());        
 }
```

And my Subscriber has a method:

```
public function subscribe(Dispatcher $events){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example you can use. And I already using this method to handle events.

#### EventServiceProvider

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\AccountEvent'   => [
            'App\Listeners\AccountEventListener',
        ],
    ];
    protected $subscribe = [
        'App\Listeners\AccountEventListener',
    ];

    public function boot( DispatcherContract $events ) {
        parent::boot( $events );

        //
    }

}
```

#### AccountEvent

```
namespace App\Events;

use App\Events\Event;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class AccountEvent extends Event {
    use SerializesModels;

    public function __construct() {
        //
    }

    public function broadcastOn() {
        return [ ];
    }
}
```

#### AccountEventListener

```
   namespace App\Listeners;

    use App\Events\AccountEvent;
    use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel as Artisan;

    class AccountEventListener implements ShouldQueue {
        protected $artisan;

        public function __construct( Artisan $as ) {
            $this->artisan = $as;
        }

        public function handle( AccountEvent $event ) {
            //
        }

        public function subscribe( $events ) {
            $events->listen( 'account.create', 'App\Listeners\AccountEventListener@onCreated' );
            $events->listen( 'account.modify', 'App\Listeners\AccountEventListener@onModify' );
        }

        public function onCreated($id) {
            try {
                log_g("AccountEventListener:init,action:onCreated,id:".$id,"debug");
                //do something as per your requirement.
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                log_g("AccountEventListener:init,action:onModify, ERROR:$msg","error");
                return response( $msg, 500 );
            }
        }

        public function onModify($id) {
            try {
                log_g("AccountEventListener:init,action:onModify,id:".$id,"debug");
                //do something as per your requirement. In my current example I'm executing command.
$this->artisan->queue( 'workflow:event', [ 'module' => "account", '--trigger' => 'modify', "--queue","--id"=> $id ] );
            } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
                log_g("AccountEventListener:init,action:onModify, ERROR:$msg","error");
                return response( $msg, 500 );
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Event Calling

```
event( "account.create",$id );
event( "account.modify",$id );
```

Please let me know if anything unclear from code example, I will explain it further with detail.